# Check exists post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I created plugin for get post title via API on submit. I used simple api request for getting data after via `wp_insert_post()` function add to DB. But i want check every time on submit to exists title. If there is a new post title then add to the database if not then it will report that 'There are no new posts'

**plugin.php**

```
        if(isset($_POST['enable'])) {

        $url='api/url';
        $result = file_get_contents($url);
        $resultData = json_decode($result);

            foreach ($resultData as  $job) {

                $post_exists = get_page_by_title( $job->JobTitle, OBJECT, 'post');

                if ( post_exists) {
                    
                    $data  = array (
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_title' => $job->JobTitle,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'post_author'   => $user_ID
                    );

                    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
                } 

            }

                echo "Done!";
        }
```

Comment: you can use post_exists() wordpress function please refer this URL https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/

Comment: @Bhautik thanks for feedback, i try this function, still same problem ( can you write code?

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @Bhautik I already checked as true answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can upvote if my answer helps you.

Comment: @Bhautik I already markered green label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
if( isset( $_POST['enable'] ) ) {

    $url        = 'api/url';
    $result     = file_get_contents( $url );
    $resultData = json_decode( $result );

    foreach ($resultData as  $job) {

        $post_title = sanitize_title( $job->JobTitle );
        $post_id    = post_exists( $post_title );

        if( !$post_id ){
            $data = array(
               'post_type'   => 'post',
               'post_title'  => $post_title,
               'post_status' => 'publish',
               'post_author' => $user_ID,
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $data );
        }else{
            //post title exist
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,
This code will return an array of all posts that match the title.

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT ID FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_title = "'.$post_title.'" AND post_status="publish"');
$post_exists = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```